# Finding two constants from CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A continuous random variable has the CDF:

$\hspace{10mm} F(x) =  \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 
0 & & x < 0 \\
cx^2 & &0 \leq x \leq 2 \\
1 & & x > 2  \end{array}\right\}$

Find the value of the positive constant $c$.

For the function to be continuous I understand that we will evaluate 4c = 1 and get the value of our constant.

My question is: What if there are two such arguments between 0 and 1. If we have two constants "c" mentioned in the same cumulative distribution function, is it impossible to find the value of the constant?

Note: the constants are the same. Both are c.

Answer (score 1):

Say you had something like

$$F(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x < 0 \\
c_1 x^2 & 0 \leq x<0.5 \\
c_2 x & 0.5 \leq x<1 \\
1 & x \geq 1 \end{cases}.$$

Say you are again given that the CDF is continuous. Then you can get an equation for continuity at $0.5$ and another equation for continuity at $1$. These equations read $c_1/4=c_2/2,c_2=1$. Thus $c_1=2,c_2=1$.

Comment: Why did you equate the two?

Comment: @user585380 I set the left and right hand limits at $x=0.5$ equal to each other so that the CDF would be continuous at $x=0.5$. Same with $x=1$.

Comment: Okay, and then you equated both the expressions to 0.5?

Comment: @user585380 No, I set the left and right hand limits, whatever those turned out to be as functions of $c_1,c_2$, equal to one another.